# Profile creation process stuck halfway Websphere

Tags: websphere

I'm creating a cell profile on Linux Mint 12 , WAS 8.0 Network Deployment Trial.
But using manageProfiles.sh or Profile Management Tool, I can not create any profile (cell, application ...). When I check the log file, the profile creation process is always stop halfway (does not show any error, just stuck there).
The log is always like this

```
<record>
    <date>2012-11-02T04:11:15</date>
    <millis>1351847475108</millis>
    <sequence>2985</sequence>
    <logger>com.ibm.ws.install.configmanager.actionengine.ant.utils.ANTLogToCmtLogAdapter</logger>
    <level>INFO</level>
    <class>com.ibm.ws.install.configmanager.actionengine.ant.utils.ANTLogToCmtLogAdapter</class>
    <method>messageLogged</method>
    <thread>0</thread>
    <message>replacing value for user.install.root (null) with (/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles)</message>
</record>
<record>
    <date>2012-11-02T04:11:15</date>
    <millis>1351847475108</millis>
    <sequence>2986</sequence>
    <logger>com.ibm.ws.install.configmanager.actionengine.ant.utils.ANTLogToCmtLogAdapter</logger>
    <level>INFO</level>
    <class>com.ibm.ws.install.configmanager.actionengine.ant.utils.ANTLogToCmtLogAdapter</class>
    <method>messageLogged</method>
    <thread>0</thread>
    <message>replacing value for was.install.root (/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer) with (/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer)</message>
</record>
<record>
    <date>2012-11-02T04:11:15</date>
    <millis>1351847475108</millis>
    <sequence>2987</sequence>
    <logger>com.ibm.ws.install.configmanager.actionengine.ant.utils.ANTLogToCmtLogAdapter</logger>
    <level>INFO</level>
    <class>com.ibm.ws.install.configmanager.actionengine.ant.utils.ANTLogToCmtLogAdapter</class>
    <method>messageLogged</method>
    <thread>0</thread>
    <message>replacing value for was.repository.root (null) with (/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/config)</message>
</record>
<record>
    <date>2012-11-02T04:11:15</date>
    <millis>1351847475108</millis>
    <sequence>2988</sequence>
    <logger>com.ibm.ws.install.configmanager.actionengine.ant.utils.ANTLogToCmtLogAdapter</logger>
    <level>INFO</level>
    <class>com.ibm.ws.install.configmanager.actionengine.ant.utils.ANTLogToCmtLogAdapter</class>
    <method>messageLogged</method>
    <thread>0</thread>
    <message>replacing value for com.ibm.ws.scripting.wsadminprops (null) with (/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/properties/wsadmin.properties)</message>
</record>
<record>
    <date>2012-11-02T04:11:15</date>
    <millis>1351847475120</millis>
    <sequence>2989</sequence>
    <logger>com.ibm.ws.install.configmanager.actionengine.ant.utils.ANTLogToCmtLogAdapter</logger>
    <level>INFO</level>
    <class>com.ibm.ws.install.configmanager.actionengine.ant.utils.ANTLogToCmtLogAdapter</class>
    <method>messageLogged</method>
    <thread>0</thread>
    <message>Resetting listener available status to: false</message>
</record>
<record>
    <date>2012-11-02T04:11:15</date>
    <millis>1351847475121</millis>
    <sequence>2990</sequence>
    <logger>com.ibm.ws.install.configmanager.actionengine.ant.utils.ANTLogToCmtLogAdapter</logger>
    <level>INFO</level>
    <class>com.ibm.ws.install.configmanager.actionengine.ant.utils.ANTLogToCmtLogAdapter</class>
    <method>messageLogged</method>
    <thread>0</thread>
    <message>setting wsadmin requester timeouts</message>
</record>
<record>
    <date>2012-11-02T04:11:15</date>
    <millis>1351847475128</millis>
    <sequence>2991</sequence>
    <logger>com.ibm.ws.install.configmanager.actionengine.ant.utils.ANTLogToCmtLogAdapter</logger>
    <level>INFO</level>
    <class>com.ibm.ws.install.configmanager.actionengine.ant.utils.ANTLogToCmtLogAdapter</class>
    <method>messageLogged</method>
    <thread>0</thread>
    <message>wsadmin requester retry count = 240000, initialization retry count = 12000, shutdown retry count = 12000</message>
</record>
<record>
    <date>2012-11-02T04:11:15</date>
    <millis>1351847475128</millis>
    <sequence>2992</sequence>
    <logger>com.ibm.ws.install.configmanager.actionengine.ant.utils.ANTLogToCmtLogAdapter</logger>
    <level>INFO</level>
    <class>com.ibm.ws.install.configmanager.actionengine.ant.utils.ANTLogToCmtLogAdapter</class>
    <method>messageLogged</method>
    <thread>0</thread>
    <message>Checking for wsadmin listener initialization</message>
</record>
```

Answer (score 10):

The IBM scripts have a bug in that they assume your default shell is bash.

You should make sure that /bin/sh maps to /bin/bash

Execute

```
ls -al /bin/sh
```

If it maps to dash execute the following:

```
sudo rm /bin/sh
sudo ln -s /bin/bash /bin/sh
```

Comment: How did you figure this out?

Comment: I came across it years ago on some IBM forum

Comment: On AIX, I got the same error if I was using bash, but profile creation worked fine when I was using ksh

Comment: There's a more canonical recipe for ubuntu (docker-friendly):
`echo "dash dash/sh boolean false" | debconf-set-selections && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive dpkg-reconfigure dash`

        p.s. But thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but on RHEL6.3 for ppc (100% supported) I also couldn't make it work. I used the: `-federateLater` true on the profile creation.

After that I manage to do:

```
./bin/addNode.sh dmgr-hostname 8879 -javaoption "-Xmx512m" -profileName MY_PROFILE_NAME
```

That did the trick, but I also wanted to do a simply federateLater false. if you got anything else, please don't hesitate to post your own answer.